# Multiple WHEN conditions?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON myTable
  WHEN old.field <> 1
    BEGIN
      UPDATE myTable...
    END;
```

How can I add multiple WHEN conditions? Like

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON myTable
  WHEN old.field <> 1
    BEGIN
      UPDATE myTable...
    END;
  ELSE WHEN old.field = 1
    BEGIN
      UPDATE myTable...
    END;
```

Do I have to create two separate triggers for it? Isn't there a faster way?

Comment: Dear, I delete my answer because I don't know but my trigger doesn't work, so I don't want communicate a nasty information. Have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON myTable
BEGIN
    UPDATE myTable... WHERE old.field <> 1 AND ... 
    UPDATE myTable... WHERE old.field = 1 AND ...
END;
```

Although I would not generally recommend that as the optimizer might not always be able to produce smart plans.

Comment: What do you mean? You take the WHERE condition from your original UPDATE statements and add the corresponding enclosing WHEN condition as an additional condition to your WHERE clause. Semantically, that is the same.

Comment: But won't the where condition check the old.field value from the rows it finds, and not from the row that's currently being updated? And what would happen when this trigger triggers another trigger on other rows?

Comment: OLD.field not change within the BEGIN/END pair. It is a reference to the row on which the trigger is fired (SQLite triggers are all FOR EACH ROW triggers). It is not touched by the DML statements that make up the trigger's body. If the update triggers other triggers, OLD/NEW will have fresh, independent values in *that* invocation frame. It is the same as recursion in, e.g., Java or C: Each invocation has its own, fresh local variables.